# Create hive table and load data Quoted CSV

Tags: linux, hive, apache-pig, hiveql, hadoop2

I have an csv file and its column can contain ','  bold in sample

sample

23,**"we,are"**,100

23,**"you,are"**,100

Requirement is load to an hive table (col1 int ,col2 array, col3 int) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Hive version is 0.14 and above you can use CSV Serde (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde). DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER for this SerDe is "

If you have previous Hive version, try to add this serde manually https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde

The thing is Serde will treat your array as a string. This is not very big problem, you can convert column into array when doing select or create additional view for the same.

Example:

```
DROP TABLE my_table;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table(col1 int , col2 string, col3 int)
row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
stored as textfile;
```

I created the text file and put it in the table location.

File content:

```
23,"we,are",100
23,"you,are",100
```

Now, get the data:

```
hive> select col1, split(col2,",") as col2, col3 from my_table;
OK
23      ["we","are"]    100
23      ["you","are"]   100
```

Alternatively you can create a view:

```
hive> create view my_table_view as select col1, split(col2,",") as col2, col3 from my_table;
OK
Time taken: 0.427 seconds
hive> select * from my_table_view;
OK
23      ["we","are"]    100
23      ["you","are"]   100
Time taken: 0.369 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

--Select array elements:

```
hive> select col1,col2[0] as col2_1, col2[1] as col2_2, col3 from my_table_view;
OK
23      we      are      100
23      you     are     100
Time taken: 0.09 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: Done. Please see my improved answer

Comment: Note, even if you will create table as containing array, anyway serde will treat it as string. This will work the same: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table(col1 int , col2 array<string>, col3 int) ...